# Hibernate query machine

Tags: java, hibernate

Please help me with hibernate query machine. I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE public.news_category_dict
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX news_category_dict_name_uindex ON public.news_category_dict (name);

CREATE TABLE public.news
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    category_id INT2,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    data TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX news_name_uindex ON public.news (name);

ALTER TABLE public.news
ADD CONSTRAINT news_news_category_dict_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES news_category_dict (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

They are linked, so I want this query

```
SELECT d.name, n.name, n.data
  FROM public.news AS n, public.news_category_dict AS d
 WHERE n.category_id = d.id
```

I know how to do it in SQL, but don't understand how to do it in HQL and With Criteria API.

Help me PLZ.

EDIT

Ok. Here are my mappings:

```
public class News implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Date created;
    private String data;

    private NewsCategoryDict category;
}
public class NewsCategoryDict implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When I use this snippet:

```
Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(News.class);
    return crit.list();
```

this SQL script I saw with tracing:

```
select
    this_.id as id1_4_0_,
    this_.category_id as category5_4_0_,
    this_.created as created2_4_0_,
    this_.data as data3_4_0_,
    this_.name as name4_4_0_ 
from
    news this_
```

And I want to see category NAME field too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two entities

```
@Entity
public class NewsDict {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "newsDict")
  private List<NewsItem> newsItems;

}

@Entity
public class NewsItem {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @Column
  private String data;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private NewsDict newsDict;

}
```

HQL

```
from NewsDict dict left join fetch dict.newsItems
```

You can change fetching `newsItems` to eager

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "newsDict", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<NewsItem> newsItems;
```

and do the same with `Criteria`

```
List<NewsDict> result = session.createCriteria(NewsDict.class).list();
```

or you can use `Criteria#setFetchMode()` with a lazy fetching.

To get `NewsDict` with `NewsItem` you can use an eager loading

```
@ManyToOne
private NewsDict newsDict;
```

or `Criteria#setFetchMode()`, or HQL with `left join fetch`.

It is just an example. It will not work with your schema. You will need to change it a bit.

Comment: Aha. I start to undestand. And what about Criteria API ?

Comment: Ok. So just getting data about Class with links - I get full info about it and all linked classes?

Comment: Ok. I undestand. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

HQL is

```
select n.name,n.newsCategoryDict.name,n.data from News n
```

News is the name of the entity class which is mapping to table public.news
In HQL,there is no SQL. All the things are object